# Login Facebook and Twitter from ZF2

Tags: php, twitter, authentication, zend-framework2, facebook-login

What do you advise me to do the login from Facebook and Twitter in my website?
I'm using Zend Framework 2.
Is there any library or module that allows me to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth :)

Comment: http://www.nsmith.net/articles/2012-10/3rd-party-includes-zf2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use ScnSocialAuth (https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth/tree/master/src/ScnSocialAuth/Service), based on HybridAuth and ZfcUser libraries. It allows registration and login for other social networks too (i.e Linkedin, Yahoo, Google etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can check Zend Framework's modules website:
http://modules.zendframework.com